# XML - Show open and close instead of empty element

Tags: php, xml

I know almost nothing about XML. This script was written for us...

I have a script that pulls info from the database and creates an XML file.
If a pulled field is empty/null, it is formatting it like so:

```
<deal_id/>
```

I know that this is valid, but I need it formatted like so:

```
<deal_id></deal_id>
```

Here is the script in question.

```
<?php
//include global config
require("config.inc.php");
//include MySQL wrapper
require("Database.singleton.php");
// instantiate database
$db = Database::obtain(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
// define basic xml data
$xml_root = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n"."<store></store>";

$deal_id = $_REQUEST['deal_id'];

$result = new SimpleXMLElement($xml_root);

$img_path = "http://www.malldeals.com/admin/images/logos/deals/";
$img_na = "image_na.jpg";

if ($deal_id != '') {

$db->connect();

// get store and deal details
$sql_store_deal = "SELECT businesses.id, businesses.business_name, businesses.business_floor, businesses.business_near, businesses.business_phone, businesses.business_address, 
                businesses.business_city, businesses.latitude, businesses.longitude, deals.title AS deal_title, deals.id AS deal_id, deals.percent_off AS deal_discount, deals.sale_price AS deal_price,
                deals.orig_price AS deal_orig_price, deals.expiry_date AS deal_expires, deals.description AS deal_text,
                    (SELECT file_name
                    FROM images
                    WHERE images.deal_id = deals.id AND size_key = '1') AS thumb2,
                        (SELECT COUNT(poster_id)
                        FROM deals
                        WHERE poster_id=businesses.id) AS num_deals
                FROM businesses, deals
                WHERE deals.poster_id=businesses.id
                AND deals.id='".$db->escape($deal_id)."'";
//
$store_deal_details = $db->query_first($sql_store_deal);
$store_logo_url = ($store_deal_details[thumb2] != "") ? ($img_path.$store_deal_details[thumb2]) : $img_path.$img_na;

$result->addChild('id', $store_deal_details[id]);
$result->addChild('name', utf8_encode($store_deal_details[business_name]));
$result->addChild('floor', utf8_encode($store_deal_details[business_floor]));
$result->addChild('near', utf8_encode($store_deal_details[business_near]));
$result->addChild('phone', utf8_encode($store_deal_details[business_phone]));
$result->addChild('latitude', $store_deal_details[latitude]);
$result->addChild('longitude', $store_deal_details[longitude]);
$result->addChild('address', utf8_encode($store_deal_details[business_address]));
$result->addChild('city', utf8_encode($store_deal_details[business_city]));
$result->addChild('num_deals', $store_deal_details[num_deals]);

$deal_discount = floatval($store_deal_details[deal_discount]);
$deal_price = floatval($store_deal_details[deal_price]);
$deal_savings = floatval($store_deal_details[deal_orig_price]) - floatval($store_deal_details[deal_price]);

$result_deal = $result->addChild('deal');
$result_deal->addChild('deal_id', $store_deal_details[deal_id]);
$result_deal->addChild('title', xml_encode($store_deal_details[deal_title]));
$result_deal->addChild('discount', $deal_discount);
$result_deal->addChild('price', $deal_price);
$result_deal->addChild('savings', $deal_savings);
$result_deal->addChild('expires', $store_deal_details[deal_expires]);
$result_deal->addChild('text', xml_encode($store_deal_details[deal_text]));
$result_deal->addChild('image', $store_logo_url);

$db->close();
}
else {
$result->addChild('error', "Missing required parameters");
}

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $result->asXML();

?>
```

Comment: Why do you *need* it formatted as such?

Comment: Needs to be formatted like that for use by a 3rd party.

Answer (score 4):

You have the choice of a few options.

1. Don't have empty elements.

   ```
   $result->addChild('deal'); // <deal/>
   $result->addChild('deal', ''); // <deal></deal>
   ```
2. Use `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG` ([docs](http://php.net/libxml.constants)) which is not available for SimpleXML (but it is easy to use the DOM with your SimpleXML object).

   ```
   $doc = dom_import_simplexml($result)->ownerDocument;
   echo $doc->saveXML(NULL, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First, all those statements are errors:

```
$result->addChild('id', $store_deal_details[id]);
```

Correct syntax is this:

```
$result->addChild('id', $store_deal_details[ 'id' ]);
```

Regarding your question, passing e.g. **' ' as the second parameter of addChild()** should create what you want.

Additionally, this

```
$result = new SimpleXMLElement( $xml_root, LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG );
```

*may* do the trick. The documentation explains this regarding the option:

```
This option is currently just available in the DOMDocument::save 
and DOMDocument::saveXML functions.
```

Comment: the constant cannot be passed to the ctor

Comment: Thx, Gordon. I rephrased my answer.

Comment: Passing '' as the second parameter isn't going to work. The blank result is actually being pulled from the database.

Comment: I proposed a non empty string containing exactly one space. SO eliminated the space during rendering my answer. Even a single space gets eliminated when printing as XML?

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

The [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.construct.php) constructor takes options as parameters. You can specify `LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG`, though the docs specify that it's only valid for `DOMDocument::save` and `DOMDocument::saveXML`

Answer (score 0):

There are many, many possible reasons to require verbose XML tags. One really common scenario is when you're using PHP to generate a property list for use in an iOS app. I ran into exactly the problem originally asked here.

For plists, it looks like the best solution is to eliminate the tag altogether, as well as its accompanying `<key>` element. For example, all of the following resulted in a "corrupted plist" error in xcode:

```
<key>someNumber</key>
<integer />

<key>someNumber</key>

<key>someNumber</key>
<integer></integer>

<key>someNumber</key>
<integer> </integer>

<key>someNumber</key>
<integer>NULL</integer>
```

The only thing that the plist spec allowed was to eliminate the two elements entirely. Fortunately, in Objective-C, when retrieving the `objectForKey` value for a key that doesn't exist in the plist, the result is simply a null value, not an error. So it was easy to trap this condition on the client side.

Just putting this out there in case someone else like me (or a future me) runs into the same situation.